# ReSharper (or something like it) for Qt?

Tags: qt

I am beginner of Qt Creator. I'm using resharper for visual studio 2005-2008 and it is very very good. Is there any tool like resharper for Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news: no, there is no equivalent tool like ReSharper for Qt Creator.

The goods news: there is an excellent [Qt Eclipse plugin](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) offers a lot more functionality than Qt Creator.

Comment: As of today (May 2012), is this still a valid answer or did something come up?

Comment: Now in October 2013, we can nearly say yes: [link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/resharper-to-support-c/)

Comment: The question shouldn't be is there a Resharper for Qt as Qt is a library for C++.  There is now a beautiful C++ version of Resharper [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) which I've recently purchase and love.  It's also included in the Ultimate Resharper 9 bundle.

Comment: What is the status in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I have just started back into the C++/Qt environment. Looks like the folks over at JetBrains are testing internal builds of Resharper 8 with c++ support.

You can submit your C++ requirements here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html?dotnetblog

Full Blog Post http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/resharper-to-support-c/

> June 26th, 2013 by Jura Gorohovsky
>
> You already know that we have been working on ReSharper 8 for quite a
>   while, improving navigation, extending the scope of XAML support and
>   introducing a project dependency viewer, among a plethora of other
>   improvements.
>
> We’re setting our sights beyond the immediate 8.0 release though: for
>   several months now, a part of the team has been working on something
>   entirely new yet requested for a couple of years already: support for
>   C++ in Visual Studio.
>
> This is a part of a wider plan to make C++ a first-class citizen of
>   JetBrains tools, along with the intent to come up with a
>   cross-platform C++ IDE announced earlier this year.
>
> C++ is a very powerful and flexible language that has never really
>   went away despite the rise and fame of its inheritors such as C# and
>   Java: there’s a lot of code being written today in C++ and will
>   continue this way for years to come. At JetBrains we feel that many
>   developers using C++ could benefit from some of the tooling that we
>   provide for other languages.